How to add a Mac user account to the deamon group — in order to install FileMaker Server in order to r&w my own data with a shell script in FMS?
I need to run shell scripts from within FileMaker server.
The default installation creates a "fmserver" user account and user group. With that user, sudo is not possible (even after adding it to the sudoers file):
Defaults:fmserver targetpw, timestamp_timeout=0, passwd_tries=1
Host_Alias FMSHOST = mms.local
fmserver    ALL = (ALL) ALL
fmserver FMSHOST = (ALL) /Library/FileMaker\ Server/*, /bin/kill 

 
bBox_Shell ( 0 ; "whoami")
fmserver
bBox_Shell ( 0 ; "echo -n \"password\" | sudo -S -u admin -s whoami")
?

Now, I could install FileMaker server for a different user (admin), that would solve the problem — because I wouldn’t need sudo anymore. However, the installer won’t let me, because the FMS user account needs to be in the daemon group.
Long story short: Is there any way to add a Mac user account to the daemon group on a Mac? Are there any drawbacks using this approach?
Thanks for any insight!

I have found the solution!

Open Terminal window and invoke su
sudo su

Paste the following commands to create user "fms" in the group "daemon":
dscl . -create /Users/fms
dscl . -create /Users/fms UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/fms RealName "FileMaker Server User"
dscl . -create /Users/fms UniqueID "510"
dscl . -create /Users/fms PrimaryGroupID 1
dscl . -create /Users/fms NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/fms
dseditgroup -o edit -a fms -t user daemon

Check if the user has been created (still sudoer)
dscl . -list /Users

Add the new user fms to the sudoers file by inserting the following line (still being a sudoer).
visudo

Add this line. The editor is vi -- you can insert the line with "i", then  and then write "w" and quit "q" vi.
fms ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Now, give the new user a password using the Mac System Preferences (or System Settings, depending on your OS)

Finally, the FileMaker Server software can be installed. Use the newly created user for that.


8 ) In FileMaker server, install the necessary plugins.
Hope this helps
